# Create custom file extension in c# .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-extension, file-format

I want to convert setup.exe file to setup.aims. When i double click to setup.aims it run like application.
Is it possible to change application extension in .net core. If possible, please provide me a demo code how it is work.

Comment: Extensions are handled by the System OS (Windows), not the Net Runtime.
The only thing that comes to mind to simulate this, is to already have a background service running, that has been associated with your extension. However, I can't see this being any helpful, as the service would have all the code, or start the actual exe file anyways, and your special file would just be a trigger, a glorified custom shortcut so to speak

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your extension to be seen as an executable in the environment variables. You can do that during the installation of your program.

```
var pathExtValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATHEXT", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATHEXT", pathExtValue + ";.AIMS", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```